# joining tables takes very long time symfony 2.7

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have the following query which takes more than 20 secs (20138ms) to return the results.

```
$locale = 'en'; // test

$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('
        SELECT
         product.id, product.productnr, ProductGrp.productgrp' . $locale . ', Criteria.criteria'.$locale.'
        FROM
            Productbundle:product product
        JOIN
            Productbundle:Criteria Criteria WITH Criteria.criteriaid =  product.criteriaid
        JOIN
            Productbundle:ProductGrp ProductGrp WITH ProductGrp.partgrpid =  product.partgrpid
        WHERE
            product.productnr =:productnr
        ')
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->setParameter('productnr', $productnr)
        ->getResult();
```

when I ran the query from "runnable query" it took about 20 secs (20.7809) in phpmyadmin.

runnable query :

```
SELECT o0_.id AS id0, o0_.productnr AS productnr1, o1_.productgrpen AS productgrpen2, o2_.criteriaen AS criteriaen3 
FROM product o0_ 
INNER JOIN Criteria o2_ ON (o2_.criteriaid = o0_.criteriaid) 
INNER JOIN ProductGrp o1_ ON (o1_.partgrpid = o0_.partgrpid) 
WHERE o0_.productnr = 'ABC1234' 
LIMIT 1;
```

However when I ran the following code in phpmyadmin it takes less than 2seconds to return the results

```
SELECT product.id, product.productnr,ProductGrp.productgrpen ,Criteria.criteriaen
FROM `product` 
INNER JOIN ProductGrp ON ProductGrp.partgrpid = product.partgrpid 
INNER JOIN Criteria ON Criteria.criteriaid = product.criteriaid 
Where productnr = 'ABC1234'
LIMIT 1
```

table size

```
-------------------------------
|Product    | over 5mill rows |
-------------------------------
|ProductGrp | over 200 rows   |
-------------------------------
|Criteria   | over 600 rows   |
-------------------------------
```

Symfony version : 2.7

Comment: Can you [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) both queries and share the result with us?

Comment: Also try running phpadmin with SQL_NO_CACHE (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache-in-select.html)

Answer (score 0):

Indexes although not listed, I would suggest the following

```
table      indexed on 
Product    (productnr, id, criteriaid, partgrpid )
Criteria   (criteriaid )  -- would expect as primary key
ProductGrp (partgrpid )   -- also would expect
```

Also, how many "locale" string version columns do you have / support.